# the indefinite article and post-modifiers of nouns

Tags: indefinite-article, post-modifier

China [in Asia] is comprised of 1.4 billion people.

The Grand Canion [in the United States of America] is so big.

[A] horn of a unicorn is very unique.

Which of these brackets are correct and which incorrect, and why?

Comment: China is NOT comprised of people. It has a population of X. And **unique** is not subject to comparison. It means the only one of its kind. So it either is unique or not unique. It is never **very** unique (although lots of native English speakers also make this mistake). You might modify your questions.

Comment: No-one would consider it necessary to tell their readers that China is in Asia. However, if you said _Tianjin, in China, has a population of X_ it would be normal to use commas rather than brackets.